# JSON - serialize only "values" of the Map using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

In my Data transfer object, I have a declaration

```
private Map<Long, StateDomain> stateDomains;
```

If you just serialize this to JSON, you will get

```
{
  stateDomains:[{"key1": stateDomain1}, {"key2": stateDomain2}...]
}
```

**that I do not want**. Instead, **I want it to become**

```
{
  stateDomains:[{stateDomain1}, {stateDomain2}...]
}
```

that is, to serialize only values of this map as a List, and discarding pairing with Long keys.

How could this be best achieved with Jackson?

Comment: Why not simply also have a `private List<StateDomain> stateDomainList` and mark your field `stateDomains` as `@JsonIgnore`?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I try to  minimize the performance hit. For best performance, I need the map. If I keep parallel field, I need to update also list in parallel. This is of course doable, but then needs a bit more logic. What I am thinking now is annotate with JsonIgnore the property and with JsonProperty the getter that just returns values set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to perform this action:

1. Dirty way:

Change getter of `stateDomains` to return only Collection of `StateDomain`:

E.g:

```
public Collection<StateDomain> getStateDomains() {
        return stateDomains.values();
 }
```

2. Create a custom `serializer` for Map:

E.g:

```
class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Map<Long, StateDomain>> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(final Map<Long, StateDomain> value, final JsonGenerator jgen, final SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeObject(value.values());
    }
}
```

Add serializer in DTO:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
private Map<Long, StateDomain> stateDomains;
```

Comment: I do not think you would call getter a dirty way. You, in fact, can name it getStateDomainsValues() and make Json Field name stateDomains via annotation.